# How can I slice a number into smaller digits to fit my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I am making a counter which will show the sum of dice rolled. At the moment if i go over 9 it turns into zero. I need to slice up the number of *zeroValue* into one digit long sections. so 123 becomes 1 <strike>23</strike>, <strike>1</strike> 2 <strike>3</strike>,  <strike>12</strike> 3. So that it fits into my array. I tried something like this:

```
function diceResult(){

var whichNumber = 123; // this number will change, depending on sum of dice rolled

var getTextNumber = new Array (9)
getTextNumber[0] = "zero";
getTextNumber[1] = "one";
getTextNumber[2] = "two";
getTextNumber[3] = "three";
getTextNumber[4] = "four";
getTextNumber[5] = "five";
getTextNumber[6] = "six";
getTextNumber[7] = "seven";
getTextNumber[8] = "eight";
getTextNumber[9] = "nine";

var zeroValue = getTextNumber[whichNumber];

var getZero = diceToolbarCounterWrapper.getElementsByTagName("li");

    getZero[2].className = zeroValue.slice(2, -0; /* <------ I tried this */
    getZero[1].className = zeroValue.slice(1, -1);
    getZero[0].className = zeroValue.slice(0, -1);

};
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Another problem with this is that if the number is under 3 digits long it removes too many digits. This is what I want to happen if the sum of dice rolled is 123:

```
getZero[2].className = "one";
getZero[1].className = "two";
getZero[0].className = "three";
```

How can I achieve this? Please add code to your answer as I am new to javaScript.

Comment: Given a number `1234` you want to convert it into `[1,2,3,4]`? I think this is the gist of what you want.

Comment: yes. Exactly. 385, would be 3,8,5. The the class name of getZero controls which number is shown, that is getZero.className = "three"; Will show the number 3.

Comment: And the `whichNumber` will always be less than 1000?

Comment: yes. It fits 40 dice, so the sum will never be over 240.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it stands `zeroValue` will be `undefined` whenever it is over 9. This is because

`var getTextNumber = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]` 
and 
`getTextNumber[123] === undefined // true`.

You would need to split `whichNumber` before you do the lookup. This is going to get very longhand, e.g. `var whichNumber1 = whichNumber.toString().slice(0,1)` and so on. Rather than go down that road, I'd recommend using `split`:

```
function diceResult(){

  var whichNumber = getSumDiceValue(); //sum of dice rolled.

  var getTextNumber = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

  var splitNumber = whichNumber.toString().split(""); // ["1", "2", "3"]

  var getZero = diceToolbarCounterWrapper.getElementsByTagName("li");

  getZero[0].className = getTextNumber[splitNumber[0]];
  if (splitNumber.length > 1) {
    getZero[1].className = getTextNumber[splitNumber[1]]
  } else {
    getZero[1].className = "";
  }
  if (splitNumber.length > 2) {
    getZero[2].className = getTextNumber[splitNumber[2]];
  } else {
    getZero[2].className = "";
  }
};
```

Edit: to solve the backwards positioning problem you could rewrite this as:

```
for (i = splitNumber.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {      
  getZero[3 - splitNumber.length + i].className = getTextNumber[splitNumber[i]];
}

if (splitNumber.length === 1) {
  getZero[0].className = "";
  getZero[1].className = "";
}

if (splitNumber.length === 2) {
  getZero[0].className = "";
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think that's a really bad way to use map. You're using it as a form of loop, which is not what its for. There are better loops you could use, and using map for this is just confusing and strange.

Comment: Yes you were actually right, it wasn't very semantic, I've removed that section of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but unfortunately the counter shows all zeros, it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Note i just updated it as I had getTextNumber and splitNumber inside out. Try it with it as it is now?

Comment: Also, you may need to explicitly blank out your getZero list items if the number has only one digit. See edited answer above.

Comment: It appears to be working now. Only problem is that the numbers are being added like this: 1=100, 2= 200, 23= 230. instead of 1= 001, 2 = 002, 23= 023.

Comment: So this is where it would be good to use a loop, and go backwards.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for some help with making that loop?

Comment: Cheers! I had many hours of headaches trying to figure this out yesterday and today! =) I'm very thankful for your help

Comment: Hey Dan, I was just about to make a new thread because I didn't want to bug you anymore since you were so helpful, but I thought it was probably better to ask you anyway. The code kind of worked, but now the numbers are turning up backwards. That is 61 becomes 016.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your quick edit. Works like a charm. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the string character by character and do what you need

```
var num = 123;
var str_num = num.toString();

for(var i = 0; i < str_num.length ; i++){
    console.log(str_num[i]);
    // if you need int
    console.log(parseInt(str_num[i]));

}
```

Comment: I'm kind a newbie. How would I go about "plugging" this into my code?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is this not exactly what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @JonSG This is basically a code only answer, which is not considered good form on SO. Read [answer] for more details.

Comment: I agree that the more description the better, but this answer has a simple description to simple code (that actually works) that solves a simple problem.  I understand not agreeing that this is "the" answer, but I don't understand flagging this as "not useful".

Answer (score 1):

It might help you understand what's going on if you give you variables meaningful names. Here's how your code reads if you do that:

```
function diceResult(){

var roll = 123; // this number will change, depending on sum of dice rolled

var words= new Array (9)
words[0] = "zero";
words[1] = "one";
words[2] = "two";
words[3] = "three";
words[4] = "four";
words[5] = "five";
words[6] = "six";
words[7] = "seven";
words[8] = "eight";
words[9] = "nine";

var word = getTextNumber[num];

var list = diceToolbarCounterWrapper.getElementsByTagName("li");

    list[2].className = word.slice(2, -0; /* <------ I tried this */
    list[1].className = word.slice(1, -1);
    list[0].className = word.slice(0, -1);

};
}
```

Now you should be able to see that you're slicing up the wrong thing. You want to use one of the digits from `roll` as an index into `words`. There are lots of ways of getting the digits from your number, but this is the simplest

```
(roll + '').split('')
```

This takes your number and turns it into a `string` (by adding it to a string), then splits it into an array of strings.

Now you need to use `parseInt()` to get the value to use to dereference your array, so you end up with this:

```
var nums = (roll+ '').split('')
list[2].className = words[parseInt(nums[0])];
list[1].className = words[parseInt(nums[1])];
list[0].className = words[parseInt(nums[2])];
```

Of course, you still have the problem of dealing with double digits instead of three, or maybe even four or more, so that becomes this:

```
var index = (roll + '').split('');
for(i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
    list[i].className = words[parseInt(index[list.length - i])];
```

This loops through the `index` array setting the `class name` you want on the `list` elements you need. The `list.length - i` bit is because you want them in reverse order.

Here's a runnable snippet demonstrating the technique:

```js
var roll = 43; // this number will change, depending on sum of dice rolled

var words = new Array (9);
words[0] = "zero";
words[1] = "one";
words[2] = "two";
words[3] = "three";
words[4] = "four";
words[5] = "five";
words[6] = "six";
words[7] = "seven";
words[8] = "eight";
words[9] = "nine";

var index = (roll + '').split('');
document.write("<p>Here's the array containing the digits of the roll: [" + index + "]</p><p>And the classes follow</p>");

for(i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
  document.write(words[parseInt(index[index.length - 1 - i])] + "<br/>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your indepth answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have worked. The counter is displaying only zeros even when the number is one digit long. Maybe I put code in wrong?

Comment: No, sorry, I put in the wrong code. I was typing in haste and didn't have the time to test what I'd written. Try it again, because I've fixed it now. I've also added a snippet to show that it works, and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to split the number:

```
function splitNum (n) {
  var digits = [n % 10];
  n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  return n == 0 ? digits : (
    splitNum(n).concat(digits)
  );
}
```

```
splitNum(0)   // [0]
splitNum(1)   // [1]
splitNum(12)  // [1, 2]
```

Then to pad the array with a couple of zeros:

```
function zeroPad (n, digits) {
  var zeros = new Array(n);
  while (n--) zeros[n] = 0;
  return zeros.concat(digits);
}
```

```
digits = splitNum(12); // [1, 2]
zeros = 3 - digits.length; // 1
digits = zeroPad(zeros, digits); // [0, 1, 2]
```

There is a shortcut though (ninjavascript):

```
num = 12 + ""; // "12"
num = new Array(4 - num.length).join("0") + num; // "012"
digits = num.split(""); // ["0", "1", "2"]
digits = digits.map(Number); // [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Number to string conversion is very expensive. And getting the digits out might become a problem for some. So here is a very simple solution. I guess this must be very very fast as well.

You can create a very simple function as follows. Well OK.. you may not chose to use the arrow functions and you may not choose declaring the default values etc.. but here is the idea.

```js
var getArr = (n, h = Math.floor(n/100)%10,
                 t = Math.floor(n/10)%10,
                 o = n%10) => h != 0 ? [h].concat(t).concat(o)
                                     :  t != 0 ? [t].concat(o)
                                               : [o];

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(getArr(7)) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(getArr(42)) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(getArr(137)) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: The OP said that there aren't always three digits. Also, division and modulus are slower than the basic string based method of getting the digits. Arrow functions are only available in ES6, and this has to run in a browser so it may not be available and should be avoided.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery: Obviously you comment and evaluate answers even before reading them. If you simply read the answer you will notice that my solution includes an answer for three digits, two digits and also one digit inputs. I believe using number to string and then from string to number type coercion  is a terrible sign of inefficiency. And as said before since you do not read the answers you have not seen my last sentence as well... "you may not chose to use the arrow functions and you may not choose declaring the default values etc.. but here is the idea."

Comment: I read your answer. You didn't read the question. Especially the last sentence explaining that the OP is new to JS. This means that they will probably have no idea how to replace an arrow function with something else, if they even know what an arrow function is in the first place. And if I misread your code, do you think it might be my fault, or because it's hard to read due to the use of new and uncommon ES6 code and the nested ternary operators? Don't blame a reviewer for misreading your code, ever! If that happens it's your fault for not making your code clear.

Comment: Well my opinion, provided they are properly indented, arrows and ternary result a much simpler to understand and beautiful to look at code, but of course i don't expect everybody to agree. On the other hand if you blame a code without even reading it or even pushing a button to see the results... then get used to be blamed. Well look... for instance i have tried your code this morning and found problems but patiently kept silent... ironically it isn't working right on the part you complain about my code. It doesn't work when a 1 or 2 digit is entered. I guess you should best fix that first.

Comment: If my answer doesn't work you should let me know in its comments. I've fixed it now. Keeping silent doesn't help anyone -- this site exists so that people can learn from these answers -- being quiet about mistakes is the last thing we need. And, like I said, I read your code -- it's not beautifully indented. And, it's still ES6 with no way for the OP to use it without learning a language they can't use in a browser. Personally, I like arrows and ternaries -- a lot, but they are difficult to read, and even more so if you're new to the language.